# Oracle PL/SQL Trigger asking for binds

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-trigger

I'm trying to create my trigger but it's asking for binds EVERY time. It works the way I want it to when I click apply on the window that appears... However, it will log an error...

My trigger checks to see if a client is active or not and do NOT allow changes if it is found to be active...

```
CREATE Trigger Client_Activity
BEFORE Insert or Update or Delete ON Client 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
    VAR_AC char(2);
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING THEN
        SELECT Activity INTO VAR_AC 
        FROM   Client_Additionals 
        WHERE  Activity = :Old.Activity;

        IF Activity = 'AC'
            THEN Raise_Application_Error(-20999, 'active')
        END IF; 
END;
/
```

ORACLE VERSION 12 USING SQLDEVELOPER

Comment: Put `SET DEFONE OFF;` before `CREATE TRIGGER .... ` statement, and press F5 `Run script`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - the same as in any case when code has bind variables. Different front ends do it differently. SQL\*Plus will just say *Bind variable "OLD" not declared*. SQL Developer will open a pop-up window, labeled "Enter binds", waiting for a value for `Old`. I believe Toad will do something similar to SQL Developer.

Comment: @krokodilko - I don't think that will cure the problem... Why would it? The issue is an (accidental, or rather misinformed) bind variable, not a substitution variable.

Comment: Anticipating the next error, which you will see after you fix the current one: shouldn't the `IF` check be on `VAR_AC`, not on `Activity`?

Answer (score 1):

You have two syntax errors in your trigger:

1. The `IF` is missing an `END IF`
2. You need to compare the content of the *variable* `var_ac`
3. You are missing a `;` after the `Raise_Application_Error()`

Putting that together, you can create the trigger without problems.

However, you need to use the "Run Script" button in SQL Developer to run a PL/SQL block like that.

[image]

SQL*Plus requires no special handling:

[image]