# Why does my trigger keep asking me for bind variables in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have this trigger where I try to change `SALESTOTALCOST` AND `PRODUCTACTUALCOST` whenever a value is inserted in `FACTPRODUCTSALES` using the `PRODUCTACTUALCOST` AND `PRODUCESALESCOST` from `DIMPRODUCT` table.

Here's the code:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER FACTPRODUCTSALES_INSERT 
AFTER INSERT ON FACTPRODUCTSALES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    ACTUALCOST NUMBER;
    SALESCOST  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT PRODUCTACTUALCOST INTO ACTUALCOST FROM DIMPRODUCT WHERE PRODUCTKEY = :NEW.PRODUCTID;
    SELECT PRODUCTSALESCOST INTO SALESCOST FROM DIMPRODUCT WHERE PRODUCTKEY = :NEW.PRODUCTID;
    
    :NEW.SALESTOTALCOST = SALESCOST * :NEW.QUANTITY;
    :NEW.PRODUCTACTUALCOST = ACTUALCOST * :NEW.QUANTITY;
END;
```

But it keeps asking me for bind variables; what is this? Why's that? And what should I do about it?

I've already tried doing `SET DEFINE OFF` base on the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737005/oracle-pl-sql-trigger-asking-for-binds) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333994/how-to-avoid-variable-substitution-in-oracle-sql-developer) and it didn't work.

Comment: You can't change new variables in an after trigger you need a **BEFORE** trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that tables exist and contain columns involved, then:

- trigger must be `before` (line #1) (if you want to modify `:new` values)
- use `:=` instead of `=` (lines #10, 11)

---

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FACTPRODUCTSALES_INSERT before INSERT ON FACTPRODUCTSALES
  2  FOR EACH ROW
  3  DECLARE
  4      ACTUALCOST NUMBER;
  5      SALESCOST  NUMBER;
  6  BEGIN
  7      SELECT PRODUCTACTUALCOST INTO ACTUALCOST FROM DIMPRODUCT WHERE PRODUCTKEY = :NEW.PRODUCTID;
  8      SELECT PRODUCTSALESCOST INTO SALESCOST FROM DIMPRODUCT WHERE PRODUCTKEY = :NEW.PRODUCTID;
  9
 10      :NEW.SALESTOTALCOST := SALESCOST * :NEW.QUANTITY;
 11      :NEW.PRODUCTACTUALCOST := ACTUALCOST * :NEW.QUANTITY;
 12  END;
 13  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```